# Django Celery - Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.8000:5672//

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to set up Django-Celery. I'm going through the tutorial

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

when I run 
    $ python manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info

I get

```
[Tasks]


/Users/msmith/Documents/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:133:     UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in     production environments!
warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2013-08-08 11:15:25,368: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/msmith/Documents/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:133: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2013-08-08 11:15:25,369: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@sfo-mpmgr ready.
[2013-08-08 11:15:25,382: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to     amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/celeryvhost: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

has anyone encountered this issue before?

settings.py

```
# Django settings for summertime project.
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'

...

INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'djcelery',
    'celerytest'
}
```

wsgi.py

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Comment: celery need message broker. I think you missed the message broker setting. you need to install rabbitmq. after installation, you need to  make vhost, user and set permissions.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update Jan 2022**: This answer is outdated. As suggested in comments, please refer to [this link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django)

The problem is that you are trying to connect to a local instance of RabbitMQ. Look at this line in your `settings.py`

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
```

If you are working currently on development, you could avoid setting up Rabbit and all the mess around it, and just use a development version of a message queue with the Django database.

Do this by replacing your previous configuration with:

```
BROKER_URL = 'django://'
```

...and add this app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('kombu.transport.django', )
```

Finally, launch the worker with:

```
./manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

Source: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/django.html

Comment: Wow, the tutorial completely ignores this bit.

Comment: The link is outdated

Comment: Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is supported out of the box now [link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django)

Answer (score 26):

I got this error because `rabbitmq` was not started. If you installed `rabbitmq` via brew you can start it using `brew services start rabbitmq`

Comment: Your answer is very important. Yes you can skip the queue but in my experience there are a number of errors created only in the queue system. Additionally, some apps are dependent on polling/similar the service for locking out access (in queue, no edit scenario). I am of the belief that Rabbit should be running "proper" and wanted to add this note as this was what I forgot as I was setting up install documentation for an app. Thanks.

Comment: I just had an interesting failure on Rabbit.  Apparently Elixir was auto-starting on local.  As such my Rabbit port was unavailable (for Django Celery). Listing all the processes by PID for the port then killing them solved connection issues once I restarted Rabbit. My fix is blunt, but underscores where other problems may exist.  Celery was giving me "consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: timed out." error locally.

Answer (score 16):

you can add these lines to your settings.py :

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

and run :

```
celery -A yourProjectName worker -l info
```

Comment: Make sure you have redis installed. Please install it from here 

https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

Then, go to programfiles/redis/ and open command prompt and write `redis-server`

next open redis client

Answer (score 4):

If you are workling on a production environment,

You have to first install and setup a rabbitmq server. You can refer rabbitmq website for installation steps.

In settings you have to write this lines:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
```

After all setup of rabitmq server you have to run this two command,

```
export C_FORCE_ROOT='true'
celery -A transcoder(name of app) worker --loglevel=info
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means celery backend settings is not proper so it is not able to connect to backend.

If you just started tutorial [celery with django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) . You can try below settings.

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.db'
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are installing Celery via pip you should select the version that you want to work with such as redis, rabbitmq, django etc.

As referred in docs: https://pypi.org/project/celery/

> Bundles
> Celery also defines a group of bundles that can be used to install Celery and the dependencies for a given feature.
>
> You can specify these in your requirements or on the pip command-line by using brackets. Multiple bundles can be specified by separating them by commas.

Example:

```
$ pip install "celery[librabbitmq]"

$ pip install "celery[librabbitmq,redis,auth,msgpack]"
```

Answer (score -1):

If all above solutions are not working, you can try with this:
`turn off your network connection (wifi or wire)`.

It's so weird but sometime it's work for me!

Seem it relates to the local network device instead of RabbitMQ service.

My screen recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13t35Lzh3JLsCbGjRag0uiDhcYz1JuHq7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you run the rabbit server in global, in my case that was the issue.

Comment: You should try to explain why the issue was cause before and how changing the server to global fixed it